# Couldn't output to console log4j 2 logs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, logging, log4j, log4j2, selenide

I'm trying to get logs output in console for my automation framework project.
I tried to use different settings, dependencies and methods to do it.

I'm using java + maven + selenide.

I added these dependencies for log4j 2

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I created this **log4j2.properties** file:

```
# configuration syntax
status=error
dest=err
name=PropertiesConfig

# publish console logs
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{DEFAULT} %c:%L - %m%n

# capture logs
logger.app.name=base
logger.app.level=debug
logger.app.additivity=false
logger.app.appenderRef.console.ref=STDOUT

# root logger
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
```

I created an instance of Logger in my BaseTest.class

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

protected static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
```

And now i'm trying to get my logs in console, by
`log.info("some string")`
in a test method.

But there is no output which is related to log4j 2 and there are no error messages in console which are related to log4j 2.

What's the possible reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

What application-server do you use? Wildfly uses JBoss logging which in turn uses slf4j. You have to provide log4j-slf4j as binding library to log with log4j2.

Try adding this dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Depending on your actual setup you could also need

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```